# Perl backticks in hash ref giving different results

Tags: perl, backticks

I have a file called a.gz which is a gzipped file which contains the following lines when unzipped:

```
a
b
```

Below are two blocks of perl code which I think "should" give the same results but they don't.

Code #1:

```
use Data::Dumper;
my $s = {
        status => 'ok',
        msg    => `zcat a.gz`
};
print Dumper($s),"\n";
```

Code #2:

```
use Data::Dumper;
my $content = `zcat a.gz`;
my $s = {
      status => 'ok',
      msg    => $content
};
print Dumper($s), "\n";
```

Code #1 gives the following result:

```
Odd number of elements in anonymous hash at ./x.pl line 8.
$VAR1 = {
          'msg' => 'a
',
          'b
' => undef,
          'status' => 'ok'
        };
```

Code #2 returns the following result:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'msg' => 'a
b
',
          'status' => 'ok'
        };
```

I'm using perl 5.10.1 running in Linux

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[perldoc perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators):

> In scalar context, it comes back as a single (potentially multi-line) string, or `undef` if the command failed. In list context, returns a list of lines (however you've defined lines with `$/` or `$INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR`), or an empty list if the command failed.

Assigning to a scalar puts ``` `` ``` in scalar context; using it in `{ ... }` puts it in list context.

`{ LIST }` takes a list and interprets its contents alternating between keys and values, i.e. `key1, value1, key2, value2, key3, value3, ...`. If the number of elements is odd, you get a warning (and the missing value is taken to be `undef`).

`LIST , LIST` (the comma operator in list context) concatenates two lists.

`=>` works just like `,` but automatically quotes the identifier to its left (if there is one).

Comment: Thanks. I wasn't aware that key/value assignment within `{....}` is array context. I thought that values are always scalar. Thanks for pointing this out.